# Could not find method finalizedBy()

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

This is my code inside build.gradle

```
task eatBreakfast {

 finalizedBy "brushYourTeeth"

 doLast{

  println "Om nom nom breakfast!"

      }

}

task brushYourTeeth {

  doLast {

  println "Brushie Brushie Brushie."

     }

}
```

Whenever I run, this is what I get

- Where: Build file '/home/android-14/gradleUdacity/build.gradle' line: 3

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradleUdacity'.
Could not find method finalizedBy() for arguments [brushYourTeeth] on root project 'gradleUdacity'.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Please specify the version of Gradle you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`task.finalizedby(...)` was [added in gradle 1.7](https://docs.gradle.org/1.7/release-notes#finalizer-tasks). Which version of gradle are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I was using the Gradle version 1.4.